# Alerting from a ble device

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Do the likes of flic, tile and pebblebee implement their own ble services/characteristics ? Or are they using standard ble profiles ?

I'm building a ble device and would like to make the phone alert/ring when a button is pressed on the device and googling doesn't suggest a standard.

Comment: You could look at the immediate alert service - https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.immediate_alert.xml but you will still need an app running on the device to act on it, so you could just as easily use a custom service

Comment: The ble device has a immediate alert service which works when sending an alert from the phone, should that service be 2way or should the phone have a separate alert service?

Comment: Which ever service you choose to implement, you will need to have an app running on the phone that connects to your BLE peripheral and acts on the button press.  A custom service with a characteristic that supports `notify` is probably simplest.  Your app will need to support background mode and state restoration to work reliably

Comment: Many thanks for your replies, I dont think I've explained myself.

Currently my iphone has an app that does what you said, it can send an immediate alert to the BLE device and the BLE device acts upon it ( turns at light on at the moment). I'm after the reverse. I want to be able to press a button on the BLE device and have the phone alert. I assume the phone has to expose an immediate alert service aswell ?

Comment: If you already have a connection between the app and the peripheral it is probably easiest for the peripheral to simply notify on a characteristic and have your app act on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer, both devices have to have a immediate alert service exposed in order to have 2 way alerting.

I'm using a microchip rn4020 which wasn't scanning the central device for services, once I corrected that i could see the phone app was presenting the immediate alert service.